# When adding "target": "blank" to links via javascript, opened tab is "recycled" (reused) - any way to prevent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

At least in safari, all links with the target added dynamically, will open in the same tab. I would like all links to open in new tabs, as is the default behavior when the target is specified in HTML (statically).

Is there a workaround?

```
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').attr({'target': 'blank'});
});
</script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a> - <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`blank` is an arbitrary window name.
You mean `_blank`.

Comment: Yes, just noticed moments ago.. DOH! Thanks